# Django Wagtail Middleware kicks error: status_code not defined in response

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-middleware

I'm in the process of upgrading a project to Django 1.11. I've rewritten a custom piece of site middleware that seems to be working; however, I'm not sure it isn't causing a problem down stream. This piece of custom middleware is called after Django and Wagtail's middleware. The error I'm getting, however, is from  Wagtail's redirect middleware:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Here is the full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailredirects/middleware.py", line 30, in process_response
    if response.status_code != 404:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Here is the middleware code from Wagtail causing the error; I note it is using the deprecation Mixin:

```
# Originally pinched from: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/redirects/middleware.py
class RedirectMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # No need to check for a redirect for non-404 responses.
        if response.status_code != 404: ...
            return response
        # If a middleware before `SiteMiddleware` returned a response the
        # `site` attribute was never set, ref #2120
        if not hasattr(request, 'site'):
            return response
```

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - it was my middleware. On the response (the second half of the middleware) I had a `return None` from the old style middleware's `process_request()` in `__call__`:

```
# BROKEN - RETURNS None
def __call__(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # If they're already auth'd, don't bother checking.
        return None
```

The middleware class object needs to return response:

```
# FIXED - RETURNS self.get_response(request)
def __call__(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # If they're already auth'd, don't bother checking.
        return self.get_response(request)
```

If you run into this error, the previous middleware in the response cycle (the one listed before the middleware reporting an error in `MIDDLEWARE[]`) will be the culprit! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here, that solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205733/1518734

> Your 404 handler must return a response with status_code=404, otherwise the Wagtail redirect middleware will not work.