# Using Django handler404 breaks Wagtail redirects

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a custom 404 handler that I use for my Django app running the CMS Wagtail. Everything works great with replacing the Django handler404 with a view function of my choosing. Except that it seems to break Wagtails 301 redirect feature. All of the redirects I have now just go to a 404 page. Below is how I am using handler404 in the base app,

```
handler404 = siteapp_views.handler404
```

Comment: What does your 404 handler look like? If it doesn't return a response with `status_code=404`, then that will probably break Wagtail's [redirect middleware](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/2d2518a571fe2890b3d5c6d624a73dc7a75329a2/wagtail/wagtailredirects/middleware.py#L33)

Comment: This was the problem. I needed to return a 404 status and it worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 404 handler must return a response with `status_code=404`, otherwise the Wagtail redirect middleware will not work.